# How many affixes are there in the word "innocuous"?

Tags: grammar

In a glance, the word "innocuous" has two affixes, i.e., a prefix "in-" and a suffix "-uous". However, I can only find the word "nocuous" in some dictionaries. So, does the word have two affixes as I thought or only one (the prefix "in-")?

Comment: It was formed in Latin.  We borrowed it whole.

Comment: I see. Does it mean that it should be considered to be without affix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that **innocuous** was taken whole from the latin, *in-* (not) and *nocuous* (harmful).

However, we also took [**nocuous**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nocuous) from the Latin, meaning (in English) likely to cause damage or injury; harmful; noxious. Although this word is rarely used (one is much more likely to see **noxious**), it does exist.

So, *in-* could be considered a prefix.

**in-** is a tricky prefix. Inflammable means *easily set on fire.* Inflatable
means *capable of being filled with air*. But incomplete means **not** *complete*, and incapable means **not** *capable*.